getServerSideProps returns error 500 only in production
I need to pre-fetch authentication status from the server.
When I include getServerSideProps the page returns 500 in production (Vercel), but runs perfectly in development (localhost).
When I remove getServerSideProps everything works well.
import { createPagesServerClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

const Dashboard = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      // content
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = (async (ctx) => {
  try {

    return {
      props: {},
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return {
      props: {
        error: error,
      },
    };
  }
});

export default Dashboard;

